# How to get rows with elements in the list column

Tags: r, data.table, stringi

I have a *datatable* as below:

```
library(data.table)

dt <- data.table(
  id = c(1:3),
  string = list(c("tree", "house", "star"),  
                c("house", "tree", "dense forest"), 
                c("apple", "orange", "grapes"))
  )
```

From this I wanted to get the rows which contains "tree" in the list string column.
So I tried

```
dt["tree" %in% string]
Empty data.table (0 rows) of 2 cols: id,string


dt["tree" %in% unlist(string)]
   id                  string
1:  1         tree,house,star
2:  2 house,tree,dense forest
3:  3     apple,orange,grapes
```

I am not sure which part I am doing it wrong.I just need id 1 and 2 to be returned.Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `string` is a list you need `sapply` or some other way to iterate over each list.

```
library(data.table)
dt[sapply(string, function(x) any(x == "tree"))]

#   id                  string
#1:  1         tree,house,star
#2:  2 house,tree,dense forest
```

Answer (score 3):

Or just

```
library(data.table)
dt[grep("\\btree\\b", string)]

   id                  string
1:  1         tree,house,star
2:  2 house,tree,dense forest
```

Looks like whats wrong with you approach is that `%in%` doesn't work on lists

```
"tree" %in% dt$string[1]
[1] FALSE
```

Whereas `grep()` or `grepl()` accepts everything it can coerce to a character vector

```
grepl("tree", dt$string[1])
[1] TRUE

as.character(dt$string[1])
[1] "c(\"tree\", \"house\", \"star\")"
```

Which means it would also match other words with `tree` inside IF as @RonakShah
reminded me you don't use word boundaries `\b`.

Comment: This would also pick the rows with the word `"treed"` or `"atree"`, any word with "tree" inside.

Answer (score 1):

We can also use `str_detect` from `stringr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
dt %>%
   filter(str_detect(string, "\\btree\\b"))
#   id                    string
#1  1         tree, house, star
#2  2 house, tree, dense forest
```

---

Or using `Map` in `data.table`

```
dt[unlist(Map(`%in%`, "tree", string))]
#   id                  string
#1:  1         tree,house,star
#2:  2 house,tree,dense forest
```